# Table insert unexisting values

Tags: mysql, sql

**Current situation** tblGamePoints

```
Id    Gamenumber    PlayerId    Game    Points
-----------------------------------------------
1     1             A           FPS     150
2     1             B           FPS     150
3     2             A           FPS     100
4     2             B           FPS     75
```

When starting gamenumber 3 I would like to add the empty rows of a game in case they do not allready have points (penalty points).

**Example 1:**

```
Id    Gamenumber    PlayerId    Game    Points
-----------------------------------------------
1     1             A           FPS     150
2     1             B           FPS     150
3     2             A           FPS     100
4     2             B           FPS     75
```

In the example above, there aren't any existing rows for gamenumber 3 so the INSERT statement should insert games with points 0 for all PlayerIds

**Example 2:**

```
Id    Gamenumber    PlayerId    Game    Points
-----------------------------------------------
1     1             A           FPS     150
2     1             B           FPS     150
3     2             A           FPS     100
4     2             B           FPS     75
5     3             A           FPS     -50
```

In example 2 player A allready has been awarded penalty points. The insert should add gamenumber 3 rows for all players except those who allready have a row 'gamenumber 3'.

**Current SQL statement used**

```
INSERT INTO tblGamePoints(Gamenumber,PlayerId,Game,Points) 
    SELECT 3,tblPlayer.Id,'FPS',0 
    FROM tblPlayer 
        LEFT JOIN tblGamePoints ON tblPlayer.Id = tblGamePoints.PlayerId 
    WHERE tblPlayer.Game='FPS' AND ValidatedEntry='1' 
        AND IFNULL(tblGamePoints.Gamenumber, 0) <> 3
```

**Current result of SQL statement used**
It adds entries for all games instead of just game 3. So it adds 5-6 records in this example instead of 1 or 2.

Comment: And you are ready to specify the number of the game for which to insert records. This doesn't need to be retrieved? Where is **ValidatedEntry** coming from?

Comment: The number of the game to be inserted I am able to retrieve. ValidatedEntry is a column of tblPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `not exists` condition seems easier to me:

```
INSERT INTO tblGamePoints (Gamenumber, PlayerId, Game, Points) 
SELECT      3, tblPlayer.Id, 'FPS', 0 
FROM        tblPlayer 
WHERE       Game = 'FPS' AND 
            ValidatedEntry='1' AND 
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM   tblGamePoints
                        WHERE  PlayerId = tblPlayer.Id AND Game = 3)
```

Comment: I am missing the options tblPlayer.Game = 'FPS' and ValidatedEntry='1' here. Though it looks indeed a lot cleaner so far.